# BYJ48 Stepper Motor- Step angle!

Tags: stepper-motor

From the datasheet:

> http://robocraft.ru/files/datasheet/28BYJ-48.pdf

and this post:

> [Stepper motors - stride angle?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60969/stepper-motors-stride) angle

I know that we need **4048** pulses to rotate the output shaft for one revolution. But when I use the module ULN 2003, with the sequence of pulses are: 1A-1B-2A-2B-... I only need **2024** pulses to rotate for one revolution.

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

You need 2048 steps, or 4096 steps, depending on what is meant by a step.

That motor (I bought some a while ago) uses 2048 *full steps*, or 4096 *half steps* per revolution.

A full step sequence is 1A-1B-2A-2B, or the higher torque 1A1B - 2A1B - 2A2B - 1A2B.

A half step sequence is 1A - 1A1B - 1B - 2A1B - 2A - 2A2B - 2B - etc

It's a bit disingenuous for them to quote 4096 half-steps as the motor resolution, as the backlash and stiffness can come to 10s of steps. But with constant load, and stepping in one direction, you can just about see half steps.

I'm not sure where the 4048 in your question came from, it's not in the data sheet. It looks like a random character combination of '4096' and '2048', binary 2^12 and 2^11.

Comment: But, in the post that I quoted above, i think, it needs 4048 full steps per revolution.  Can you give me a formula to calculate the step angle from the datasheet? Thank you!

Comment: If it says 4048, that's a misprint, somebody doesn't know their binary! You'll notice it's the first part of 4096, and the second part of 2048! The angle of 5.625 they quote in the datasheet is 1/64th of 360 degrees, and the gearbox is 64:1. If you register the zero position carefully, you'll find 2048 full steps are needed per revolution to return to zero. Remember the backlash is big enough to swallow the difference between 2024 and 2048 steps, do at least 2 revolutions in the same direction.

Comment: Because of "_The angle of 5.625 they quote in the datasheet is 1/64th of 360 degrees, and the gearbox is 64:1_" so, it needs 64*64=4096 steps for per revolution. Is it right ?

Comment: Yes. It also helps that I've done the experiment with a fragment of mirror on the motor shaft, a laser pointer, and a bit of tape on the wall, confirming the 4096 and refuting the 4048.

Answer (score 1):

From the datasheet, it should be 4096 full steps ( stepper motor and gearbox together ). The correct sequence to apply is 1A1B - 2A1B - 2A2B - 1A2B like Neil said for full torque, where A and B are the center taps .... There are four steps in that pattern. Any change to windings is considered a step.

Comment: Yeah, it is 4096 full steps. And i think, the sequence (1A1B - 2A1B - 2A2B - 1A2B) and (1A-1B-2A-2B) are all _full steps_. (1A1B - 2A1B - 2A2B - 1A2B) only makes a biggger torque than (1A-1B-2A-2B).